# How to make automaic refresh in ScrolledComposite SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have a problem that after I build my shell and open it , I need to add graphic elements to the shell after it’s open during runtime
And the issue that once the shell is open I can’t see the new graphic elements which were added.
The new graphic elements appears just in case I resize the size of the shell.

Is there a way you to fix this issue and to see the refresh automatically
Here is simple example that:
1-  I added 10 buttons of A to a tab folder and open the shell.
2-  Then I added 10 buttons of B to the shell
3-  I can see the button B just if resize the shell

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class TabFolder
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();

        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(500, 500);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        final CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        folder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        folder.setSize(500, 500);

        CTabItem item = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.CLOSE);

        final ScrolledComposite scrollComp = new ScrolledComposite(folder, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        item.setControl(scrollComp);

        final Composite tab1Comp = new Composite(scrollComp, SWT.NONE);
        tab1Comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
        tab1Comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        scrollComp.setContent(tab1Comp);
        scrollComp.setExpandVertical(true);
        scrollComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrollComp.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter()
        {
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e)
            {
                Rectangle r = scrollComp.getClientArea();
                scrollComp.setMinSize(folder.computeSize(r.width, SWT.DEFAULT));
            }
        });

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            Button text = new Button(tab1Comp, SWT.NONE);
            text.setText("A");
        }

        shell.open();

        for (int x = 10; x < 20; x++)
        {
            Button text = new Button(tab1Comp, SWT.NONE);
            text.setText("B");
        }
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `tab1Comp.layout()` after adding your B-buttons because the layout is not automatically updated after programmatic changes. You also have to update the minimum size of your `ScrolledComposite`, because `controlResized(...)` is also not called after programmatic changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer
Appreciated  for your help